# Android - Post a notification to status bar?

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I am trying to post a notification to the status bar without any intent, but nothing is happening?
Am I missing anything? This code is inside my push notification receiver service.

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
        this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Hello");
    builder.setContentTitle("This is my message");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setFullScreenIntent(intent, true);

    notificationManager.notify(555, builder.build());
```

Comment: You also need a [small icon](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int)). Also, an Intent *will* be needed if you want this code to run on 2.2 and 2.3.

Comment: Awesome please post that as an answer so I can accept

Comment: Done. Good to see that your problem is fixed!

Comment: Just to mention, you are calling setContentTitle two times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, to create a notification for the notification manager, a [small icon](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setSmallIcon%28int%29) must also be provided.

Additionally, for developers targeting Android 2.2 and 2.3 as well, make sure to include a content Intent otherwise the app will crash.